# View a PDF in React Native

Tags: pdf, webview, react-native

Can anyone please provide sample code for displaying a PDF in React Native?  iOS and Android.

This is what I've tried:

```
  render: function() {
    return <WebView
      source={require('./my.pdf')}
      />
  }
```

^ This results in a Red Screen of Death with the "Unable to resolve module" error.

```
  render: function() {
    return <WebView
      source={{uri: 'my.pdf'}}
      />
  }
```

^ This gives an "Error Loading Page" message in the WebView.  "The requested URL was not found on this server"

I know iOS is capable of showing a PDF in a UIWebView. I assume Android can do the same.  There must be something in how the source is specified that I'm missing.

Comment: I presume you've found this already, which is an android only solution https://github.com/cnjon/react-native-pdf-view though it appears they're working on iOS. They've bridged to native for their solution. You may gain insight if you took the time to dig in. I'd love to hear whether it's possible to load pdfs locally into webview though.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman I've seen that.  I'm a native iOS developer by trade, so I could setup a bridge there as well.  I know I could make it work that way.  Just hoping I don't need to jump thru those hoops.

Comment: I hear you. If you do, perhaps consider contributing to the above package so the next guy (maybe me!!) won't have to :)

Comment: **Android solution:** [Link to detailed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662309/how-to-save-pdf-to-android-file-system-and-then-view-pdf-react-native/38804845#38804845). Enjoy!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, for future generations, here's how I solved this problem:

**Updated September 13, 2017:**

There is a new NPM module that makes this entire process much easier. I would suggest using it going forward instead of my original answer below:

[react-native-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf)

Once installed, rendering the PDF is as easy as this:

```
export default class YourClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pdf = null;
  }

  render() {
    let yourPDFURI = {uri:'bundle-assets://pdf/YourPDF.pdf', cache: true};

    return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Pdf ref={(pdf)=>{this.pdf = pdf;}}
        source={yourPDFURI}
        style={{flex: 1}}
        onError={(error)=>{console.log(error);}} />
    </View>
  }
}
```

Just put your actual pdf in the `android/app/src/main/assets/pdf` folder of your project.

**Original Answer:**

**iOS**

```
render: function() {
  return <WebView source={{uri: 'My.pdf'}}/>
}
```

The trick is that you need to include `My.pdf` into your project in Xcode and make sure it's added to your build target.

Just copying it into your React Native project folder wasn't enough. It had to be part of the Xcode project itself.

**Android**

It appears that Android did not provide a native PDF viewer until 5.0 (Lollipop).  To get around this, I've had to make use of three key techniques:

1. Pull the PDF out of my APK bundle and store it in the `files` folder for my app.  This SO answer was very helpful in accomplishing this:

[Android: How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4530294/271976)

I tweaked the code a bit so that the file wasn't going to an `sdcard` but to my app's `files` folder.  Here's what I added to my `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
  String[] files = null;

  try {
      files = assetManager.list("pdf");
  } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
  }

  if (files != null) for (String filename : files) {
      InputStream in = null;
      OutputStream out = null;

      try {
        in = assetManager.open("pdf/" + filename);

        File outFile = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        copyFile(in, out);
        Log.e("tag", "Copy was a success: " + outFile.getPath());
      } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + "pdf/" + filename, e);
      }
      finally {
          if (in != null) {
              try {
                  in.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // NOOP
              }
          }
          if (out != null) {
              try {
                  out.close();
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // NOOP
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
      out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

I also made sure my PDF is in the `assets/pdf` folder under `android/app/src/main`

2. I then utilized the [react-native-fs](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs) package to get the absolute URL to my PDF, which is now in the `files` folder:

   ```
   var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
   var absolutePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/My.pdf';
   ```
3. With all of this in place, I used [react-native-pdf-view](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi3x8Km3dXLAhVKSyYKHej6AH8QFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fcnjon%2Freact-native-pdf-view&usg=AFQjCNE_M9g0nkNnTlnaJUpSw71X1ttCzw&sig2=sbt_cU9pUbfx__KWDHClGA) to actually load and display the PDF:

   ```
   import PDFView from 'react-native-pdf-view';

   render: function() {
     var absolutePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/My.pdf';

     return <PDFView
       ref={(pdf)=>{this.pdfView = pdf;}}
       src={absolutePath}
       style={ActharStyles.fullCover} />
   }
   ```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, it helped, but I am facing issue that I am not able to scroll the pdf , did you face the issue ?

Comment: I did not, sorry.  I would suggest opening a new Question with sample code and the community will try to help.  Good luck!

Comment: **Android solution:** [Link to detailed solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662309/how-to-save-pdf-to-android-file-system-and-then-view-pdf-react-native/38804845#38804845). Enjoy!

Comment: @Axeva do you have any idea how to support zoom?

Comment: @zianwar on which platform? iOS or Android?

Comment: @Axeva ideally both, but i need iOS now?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no text search in react-native-pdf library.

Comment: would have loved to use the react-native-pdf but I am new to React and React Native, and I can't run the react-native link commands due to Expo. Detaching the project from Expo seems like a huge deal and me and my team really would like to keep Expo. :(

Comment: This solution made my expo project very complicated, I ended up using rn-pdf-reader-js instead.

Comment: is there a way that i can disable horizontal and vertical swipe in react-native-pdf? i want to change page only when user presses the button.

Answer (score 18):

A simple solution for this problem is to set `<WebView>` `source/uri` to this:

```
https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url={your pdf url}’
```

Comment: Actually a better solution is to use this: https://github.com/mozilla/PDF.js/wiki/Viewer-options since it support jumps to page numbers. And as far as I know the google drive viewer has limitation on uses/day

Comment: If I need to pass some headers to PDF url, how I can do it?

Comment: Here's an example to display just a PDD: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf

Here's one displaying the same PDF but opens at page 3:

http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf#page=3

Answer (score 3):

The Amazon S3 Presigned URL contains query string contains "?" and "&" which confuses the outer URL.

So you have to Encode the S3 Presigned URL before passing it to the Google Doc Viewer.

Like this:

```
var encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(presigned_url);
```

var iFrameUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/gview?url=' + encodedUrl;

Answer (score 1):

Just add `style={{flex:1}}` in the opening View Tag of your return and you should be fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more and show the block of code please?

Answer (score 1):

```
In case of pdf url this will do

openLink(url) {
    return Linking.canOpenURL(url)
      .then(supported => {
        if (!supported) {
          console.log("Can't handle url: " + url);
          this.showFlashMessage('Not supported in your device');
        } else {
          return Linking.openURL(url);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
  }
```