# React-native - Populate Image with file path to base64

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-fs

When I receive a base64 Image from the server I save it to the android file system.
Is it possible to give an Image the path to the the base64 to populate the Image.

For example, something like this:

```
<Image source={uri: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image.jpg"} />
```

Thanks.

---

**Edit** @Xeijp

---

I save the following base64 image to the android file system :

```
var imageBase64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+base64Str;
```

I save it to the picture directory:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image.jpg
```

I then populatate the image like this:

```
<Image source={{uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image.jpg"}} style={styles.image} />
```

The image is still not rendering.

Any ideas??

Comment: did you manage to figure out how to do this?

Comment: @Salman Hasrat Khan   Similar to solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658716/react-native-pdf-view-how-to-populate-pdfview-with-base64-or-blob

Answer (score 1):

On Android, when using `uri` path as source of `Image` element you need to add prefix `file://` otherwise it won't work.

```
    <Image source={{ uri : 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image.jpg' }}/>
```

Comment: It is still not working. check out my edit on the question. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using require to load the image from file path and then pass it to Image:

```
const imageFromFile= require('/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Image.jpg');

<Image source={imageFromFile} style={styles.image} />
```