# View base64 pdf in webview react native on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

Here is what I am trying

```
const [pdf, setPdf] = useState("")

let image = "data:application/pdf;base64," + curr.Body.toString('base64');

setPdf(image)

<WebView
            style={styles.pdf}
            useWebKit={true}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
            source={{
                html: `
            <html>
            <object data="${pdf}" type="application/pdf">
                <embed 
                    scrollbar="1" 
                    src="${pdf}" 
                    type="application/pdf" 
                   
                />
            </object>
            </html>
            ` }}
        />
```

the below is what i am getting. The PDF contains 5 pages but i am getting only one on the screen.

[image]

help me to get the full pdf to the view.

Comment: please include the pdf style so we can have a look on it

Comment: @chikabala  flex: 1

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your code with a ScrollView to make the content visible/scrollable :

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
      >
        <WebView
            style={styles.pdf}
            useWebKit={true}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={true}
            source={{
                html: `
            <html>
            <object data="${pdf}" type="application/pdf">
                <embed 
                    scrollbar="1" 
                    src="${pdf}" 
                    type="application/pdf" 
                   
                />
            </object>
            </html>
            ` }}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Or you can use a library dedicated for reading pdfs, such as :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-pdf-reader-js
Here is an example :

```
<PDFReader
    style={{flex:1, flexGrow:1}}
        source={{
          uri: 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf',
        }}
      />
```

Comment: didn't helped chikabala , so i am getting only one page from the entire pdf file actually it contains 5 pages

Comment: try to add `javaScriptEnabled={true}` to your `WebView`

Comment: no didn't helped and the data="${pdf}" is base64

Comment: try to look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38804802/15336413

Comment: that solution wont help me

Comment: @vijay please check my update

Comment: i am restricted to use libraries

Comment: try creating a snack if u could that will help

Comment: you want the entire component ?

Comment: yes upload you're component to snack

Comment: that's it the above code is the component

Answer (score 0):

This is by default/design.

Safari renderer will render only 1st page on iOS.

https://caniuse.com/pdf-viewer

> When displaying PDFs inline rather than separately, iOS Safari will only display the first page of the document.