# React-Native-Pdf can't set the source from the app iteself

Tags: react-native, react-native-pdf

In my RN application, I use react-native-pdf. I want to show a file which is in the file system of the app. But when I set the source it doesn't work and the app can't identify the path. How can I set the path properly?

```
<Pdf
  source={{ uri:'file:///terms.pdf'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be below. when I tried that, it worked. And there is no bug about that on the repository of react-native-pdf. Maybe your version of react-native-pdf has bug. You should get this version => 5.1.6.

```
<Pdf
  source={uri:"file:///absolute/path/to/terms.pdf"}
/>
```

Comment: What is the absoulte/path/to/ here? I dont understand this.

Comment: you can check this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/35925218/456588